# Pressing Ctrl-L or Ctrl-D inserts an "@s" in Konsole

Tags: terminal, konsole

I'm using fish, but I've tried doing `konsole -e bash` as well (it inserts a visible "s") there. It seems pressing certain Ctrl-* key combos inserts a Ctrl-S before actually sending that particular escape sequence in. For instance, Ctrl-L clears the screen and inserts an @s after my prompt, as if I'd typed it in before the Ctrl-L.

I've disabled the "flow control" thing already.

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` say?

Comment: @dirkt `xterm-256color` (in `fish`, `bash`, and `fish` on `tmux`).